# Regex to extract a word in front of numbers between spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have this string for Example

> Shop 1, some street here **Mooloolaba** **4557** QLD Australia

I want to detect the postal code and get what is in front of it.

I'm trying this regex without any success:

```
\s(.*?)\s(\d{4})
```

I only want to get `Mooloolaba` and `4557`

Comment: Forgot to say string always change for each shop but city and postal code are always there

Comment: Can the city name have spaces like "New York" ?

Comment: for your example this will work: https://regex101.com/r/u8JC1q/1 , but if you have another example with another case, then you should take care of that too

Comment: I think it's impossible if citys has spaces between them, because regex can't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(\S+)\s+(\d{4})\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z15Cch/2)

Regex Breakup:

- `(\S+)` - Match and capture one or more non-white-space characters
- `\s+` - Match one or more white-space characters
- `(\d{4})` - Match and capture four digits
- `\b` - assert a word boundary